# xamarin - Missing Component in System.Data.Oledb.dll

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to build an android app to use oledb to access my ms access file(.mdb). But I found that there is no any class defined in System.Data.Oledb except enum "OledbType" when I add reference of System.Data .

However, Xamarin api doc state there are many class defined in System.Data.Oledb namespace.

I check the System.Data version : 2.0.5.0 & file version: 4.0.50524.0

Comment: Can you post the link to their documentation? I've been fooled quite a few times because they have documentation about just about everything, but it doesn't mean you can use it on android. For example: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Windows.Forms.Form/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found System.Data.Oledb and some functionality are removed in System.Data.dll . This page show the available assemblies on different platform: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/available-assemblies/